# Append content after a specific string in a file?

Tags: ruby

I have this file:

```
# file.txt
My first name is Foo
and my last name is Bar.
I live in Baz.
```

I want to add:

```
My number is Baz.
```

after:

```
My first name is Foo
and my last name is Bar.
```

So the result will be:

```
My first name is Foo
and my last name is Bar.
My number is Baz.
I live in Baz.
```

How could I do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure someone can post a more idiomatic version, but

```
tmp=File.open('temp','w')
File.open(file, 'r') do |f|
   while line=f.gets
     tmp.write(line)
     tmp.write(value) if line == "value to match"
  end
end
tmp.close
```